# How many breaks does it take to divide a chocolate completely?

Tags: scala, recursion, int

CodeWars challenges again. Today I have a problem with this one:

"Your task is to split the chocolate bar of given dimension n x m into small squares. Each square is of size 1x1 and unbreakable. Implement a function that will return a minimum number of breaks needed.

For example, if you are given a chocolate bar of size 2 x 1 you can split it to single squares in just one break, but for size 3 x 1 you must do two breaks.

If input data is invalid you should return 0 (as in no breaks are needed if we do not have any chocolate to split). Input will always be a non-negative integer."

For some reason, the output is constantly 0 no matter what sides of the chocolate bar I provide.

What I've already tried:

```
object breakChocolate {

    var result = 0

    def breakChocolate(n: Int, m: Int) = {

        var t = n*m
        var i =0
        def breaking(y:Int): Unit ={
            if (t ==0 || t ==1)
                result = i
            else {
                breaking(t%2)
                i +=1
            }
        }
        result
    }
}
```

Here are the tests:

> Test Results:
>    TestCases
>    breakChocolate(5, 5) should return 24
>   Test Failed
>
> 0 was not equal to 24
>    Stack Trace
>   Completed in 38ms
>    breakChocolate(7, 4) should return 27
>   Test Failed
>
> 0 was not equal to 27
>    Stack Trace
>   Completed in 1ms
>   Completed in 76ms

Comment: I'm not going to comment on the algorithm itself, but the reason your code will always return `0` is pretty straightforward: you've defined a method `breaking` which modifies `result`, but you're never actually calling it.

Comment: fun question. started doodling with pen & paper and noticed a correlation between the dimensions and number of cuts required. Any `2x2` requires 3 cuts, any `2x3` requires 5 cuts, any `3x3` requires 8 cuts, any `3x4` requires 11 cuts... noticing a pattern?

Comment: Yes, it means that the number of cuts will always be one times times smaller than the total number of all the pieces. Ahh ok get it now. I am just thinking of a derivative of a math algorithm to explain the whole thing in terms of language of maths, but yes I do get the general idea :)

Comment: Btw, sorry for the late reply, was on a holiday :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this problem you don't need recursion at all. Consider the special case of chocolate plate: (1 x n). To divide this plate completely you need (n-1) breaks. Now you have plate m x n. To divide it into m pieces of form (1 x n) you need (m-1) breaks. So the total number of breaks is

```
(m-1) + m*(n-1) ~ 
m - 1 + m*n - m ~ 
m*n - 1
```

Comment: Cheers, that seems to answer my problem completely.

Comment: Just one question. In the first line, why did you add (m-1)+ m*(n-1)?

Comment: We are breaking a bar of chocolate of size m*n. I understand where the n-1 come from, but why did you add (m-1) to it. Is it because we need to include the breaking of the n bit as well as the m bit?

Comment: What if m and n are very high values say 10^9 each?

Comment: No matter. If you mean numeric overflow then you can use some type that can handle numbers up to, say 10^20

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading the Scala correctly, you've got the basic algorithm wrong.

This is actually a very simply problem, something similar to the old puzzle: if you have 55 teams playing in a single-elimination tournament, obviously some of them have to get byes in the first round, so there won't be a perfect even bracket.  So how many total games will be played?

The answer: 54.  Regardless of how the bracket is made, it's a single-elimination tourney.  Every game reduces the number of remaining teams by one.  So to get 55 participants down to one winner, 54 games will have to be played.

There is a similar argument to be made for your chocolate bar.  At some point, you have `p` pieces of chocolate in front of you.  Whichever one you select to break, you have taken `1` from the pile and put back `2`, which means that the pile now has `p + 1` pieces.  So for every split you add one piece to the pile.  This should lead directly to an answer...

...which may actually be wrong because of the need to return `0` in some cases, but it should be easy to special-case that.

Comment: Fun problem and very relevant points in your post. I worked through it visually but ultimately came up with the same answer. I particularly like your `p + 1` bit, that really solidified the reasoning for me. Thanks for sharing, Scott.

Answer (score 0):

You get 0 because you are not running `breaking`.

If you want to use recursion, one option could be to use a tail recursive function.

First decrement `a` checking it is greater than 1 to get the number of "horizontal" breaks to get the slices. Add 1 to the accumulator while looping.

Then decrement `b` checking it is greater than 1 to get the number of "vertical" breaks. This time add the starting "horizonal" value because that is the number of times you actually have to break the slices.

```
object breakChocolate {    
  def breakChocolate(n: Int, m: Int): Int = {
    def breaking(a: Int, b: Int, acc: Int = 0): Int = {
      if (a > 1) breaking(a - 1, b, acc + 1)
      else if (b > 1) breaking(a, b - 1, acc + n)
      else acc
    }
    breaking(n, m)
  }
}
```

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/v3x35e)

Comment: Correct, but that's still a lot of work for the equivalent of `n * m - 1`.

Comment: @jwvh That is correct :) it is just an example of how you might reason about it in a recursive manner.

Comment: To my surprise, this problem is reduced to simple arithmetic. While it's nice to see the recursive solution, there's no hint or suggestion that the algorithm presented here would arrive at the *optimum* number of cuts. It just so happens that for this particular problem, no matter where you cut, the same number of cuts is required for the same input chocolate. You got lucky this time :D

Comment: @user633183 Thank you for your comment. The OP tried using a recursive solution that is why I added a  possible solution. I explained how I thought how one might go about it, I don't think it was luck though :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead:

```
  function breakChocolate(n,m) {
   if(n > 0 && m > 0) {
      return n * m - 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the accepted answer? (BTW, this is Scala. Don't need `return`.)

Comment: Yes, but we also have to test  if the input data is valid or not. If there is  any  chocolate to  split it returns the number. But if the  data is invalid e.g:- (-1) or 0, it will return 0.

Comment: I would think a negative result would be a pretty good indicator of invalid input but, OK, if you feel using zero as the standard indicator is significant then why isn't that mentioned in the posted answer? Code-only answers are discouraged here on SO. Also, this is a Scala question but the code in your answer isn't Scala.